# Apache 2.2 + PHP 5.3.2 + cURL not working

Tags: php, apache-2.2, curl

When I try to start the Apache server (with PHP and cURL extension), it says:

```
The Apache2.2 service is restarting.
Starting the Apache2.2 service
The Apache2.2 service is running.
rmine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.8 for ServerName
[Tue Sep 07 14:30:57 2010] [warn] pid file C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

(I'm guessing that the fourth line should start something line "Determine"; probably a race condition.)

Then it terminates (and if I retry I get the same "unclean" message). If I comment out the `extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini, httpd.exe works again. The PHP error log is empty.

When I run php-cli, cURL functions normally, so it must be caused by some magic behind the scenes that I don't know anything about.

Suggestions? Can I retrieve more information some way? Thanks!

**Edit:** Apache + PHP works nicely without cURL.

Comment: Does `php_curl.dll` in fact exist?

Comment: php_curl.dll exists (I just edited). Works with php-cli.

Comment: I was hoping to keep it here since I've been spoiled with good answers here. :)

Comment: Surely to be closed but until then: Have you got the right versions of the relevant DLLs? Typically when I have Apache/PHP issues it's because I was using a wrong version of a library, whether that's different platforms, releases, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You might be using the wrong PHP version :

> Which version do I choose?
>
> If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or Apache2 from apache.org you need to use the VC6 
>   versions of PHP

So first make sure you're using VC6 (Thread safe) and check if that solves the problem, or alternatively remove your current apache, php and mysql and install [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/).

Comment: I was already using VC6 TS for Apache 2.2 plug-in, but upgraded to PHP 5.3.3 and that did the trick for me. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like non-production server to me. You can install XAMPP or WAMPP, it has all the extensions already functioning out of the box. No need to waste time with server config.

[XAMPP] - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

[WAMPP] - http://www.wampserver.com/en/